# Can not set image on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am trying to set a new image for every ImageView in my layout by following code. It does not generate any error. But pictures of the ImageViews does not change.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_desert, null);

    int count = rl.getChildCount();

    Log.d("COUNT", "***************************** Child count = " + count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count ; ++i){
        ImageView im = (ImageView)rl.getChildAt(i);
        im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kunefem));
    }
```

Here is my xml file content:
activity_desert.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Desserts"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image0"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="305dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image0" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image0"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image0" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image4"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/image5"
    android:src="@drawable/dessert2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image3" />
```

I am frustrated! Please help!

Comment: you haven't asked a question, or told us what is (or not) happening.

Comment: Exactly what @panini said, where's your logcat & question?

Comment: What is the problem? Can you not set the image? Is the image not displayed, but something else is? Is the layout displayed? More specifically describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry for bad question. Fixed a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
```

Then try accessing the child views of that object fetched.

EDIT: Apparently this worked, I'm glad this answered your question!

I wanted to add a little bit more of an explanation of why this worked. When it comes to actually grabbing the View objects from any layout.xml file, you have to use the findViewById method. A LayoutInflater instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding view objects. Glad this helped you out!